# Why does the loop run ten times instead of nine times? Is not ten greater than ten?

Tags: oracle

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
    Fate number;
BEGIN
    Fate:=1;
    LOOP
       IF Fate>10 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('end');
          EXIT;
       END IF; 
       dbms_output.put_line(Fate);    
       Fate:=Fate+1; 
    END LOOP;    
END;
```

It runs 10 times instead of 9 times. Why? It should exit the loop at 10 but it runs the statement for another time which is 10.

Comment: "Is ten not greater than ten?" - Er, no: ten equals ten!

Answer (score 2):

Because condition should be

```
if fate >= 10
```

or

```
if fate > 9
```